# Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module "Users/myhUser/downloads/myFolder/my.Json/"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to push firebase functions with node.js and terminal. When I push and check my logs in firebase I am seeing,

> Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '/Users/myUser/Downloads/myFolder/my.Json'

and

> Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?

In my node.js file, I have

```
var serviceAccount = require('/Users/myUser/Downloads/myFolder/my.Json');

 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 admin.initializeApp({
 credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
 databaseURL: "https://myproject.firebaseio.com"
 });
```

I have tried to find fixes on here but not sure what it is I am supposed to be looking for. Didn't I initialize the file correctly? I have NPM installed and updated and all of my credentials matched. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use absolute paths to scripts with `require` on Cloud Functions.  You will need to use a relative path, and make sure the file is in the functions folder.  The Firebase CLI will only deploy the files in the functions folder.  So, if you copy my.Json to sit next to node.js, you should be able to require it like this:

```
var serviceAccount = require('./my.Json');
```